# Progress ABL How to Test for WEBSPEED in the PRE-PROCESSOR

Tags: preprocessor, progress-4gl, openedge

I want to conditionally compile some blocks of code depending on type of client i'm running in.  this is fine for batch and tty as i can use the {&BATCH-MODE} but how to test for when the code is being compiled in webspeed agent? eg. {&IF} not {&SOMETHING} EQ "YES"  {&THEN}
{&ANALYSE-SUSPEND}
foo
bar
{&ANALYSE-RESUME}
{&ENDIF} 
it would be helpful if this did not rely on defines  auto generated by the architect in .w's etc but that would be a nice to have not essential.

Comment: sry ken oops cap lock coding all night n sleepy corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out this morning {&webstream} and {&out} are not defined in in normal sessions so i can just test for that. runtime is not an issue in my case i just want to compile the code in all cases. in this shop dont ask me why but every single piece of code is session compiled. poor cpu but there u go.  i could be defensive and add some logic with session:Client-type for bells and whistles you're right. if not can-do then boogie :)

Answer (score 2):

Compile time isn't run time. If the program can be run different ways (as a part of a of webpage using webspeed, as a part of a batch and as a part of some other kind of client etc) you're most likely better of evaluating this in run time instead.

You can identify in what environment you're running:

**SESSION:CLIENT-TYPE**

This will identify your type of client.

```
DISPLAY SESSION:CLIENT-TYPE.

Type of client                   Attribute value
-------------------------------- -----------------------
ProVision standard ABL client    4GLCLIENT
WebClient                        WEBCLIENT
AppServer agent                  APPSERVER
WebSpeed agent                   WEBSPEED
Pacific Application Server agent  MULTI-SESSION-AGENT
Other special-purpose clients     Unknown value (?)
```

[Documentation](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge116/openedge116/#page/dvref/client-type-attribute.html#)

**Using VST**

If you have at least one database connected
_Connect-ClientType tells you what kind of client this particular connection is:

```
Value    Client
-------- ---------------------
ABL      ABL client
SQLC     SQL client
WTA      Webspeed agent
APSV     AppServer agent
SQFC     SQL Federated client
```

Example:

```
FIND FIRST _myconnection NO-LOCK.
FIND FIRST _connect NO-LOCK WHERE _connect._connect-usr = _myconnection._MyConn-userid.
DISPLAY _connect._Connect-ClientType.
```

**Based on OS**

Perhaps you run different OS:es?

```
DISPLAY OPSYS.
```

**Other ways**

There's a number of other ways of doing this, including perhaps looking at PROPATH, Working directory etc.

Try to stick with a solution that won't change over the course of time because of Progress upgrades, new OS:es, new directory structures etc.

Comment: thanks for the input but it has to be compile time i know i can get the session handle info in rt.  issue is differing propaths in ws and ( chui & -b) , legacy naming convention conflict between both propath . tried to get them to rationalize the propaths and conflict and merge but hit a political . brick wall on that direction. testing propath would be an option since its a in the preprocessor. but then propath might change so parsing that and relying on it over time not good idea.  so i guess the include file option prob best workaround

Comment: Good luck! Remember that programs compiled in one environment might run in another (and behavior wont change since conditions where set at compile time).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there is no such preprocessor variable out of the box.

But you could create your own include file and include that in the code that's relevant. You need two versions of that file, one says

&GLOBAL-DEFINE WebSpeed WebSpeed

and the other

&GLOBAL-DEFINE NoWebSpeed NoWebSpeed

And then configure your compile sessions so that they find exactly one of the files in propath.

But as you will agree, this is probably dangerous as the result will heavily rely on the proper PROPATH used during compilation. I'd rather attempt to use a runtime condition instead.

What are you trying to achieve in detail?

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspicions both answers were helpfull. include route i guess or overriding cgidefs.i